# Red square appears around radio button control when clicked in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, mvvm-light

I have a set of radio buttons which are displayed correctly (shown in image below).
Now when i click on them a red square seems to appear around them(shown in 2nd image below).
this remind of rendering issue with wpf as i seen similiar with winforms previously.

Correct behavior:
[image]

Error behavior image:
[image]

As for the development i'm using wpf with c#, mvvmlight.

Also iv included my code below:

```
  <RadioButton GroupName="Part_GrpPlayBtn" 
                                     ToolTip="Play" 
                                     Style="{StaticResource StyleRadioButton}" 
                                     Template="{StaticResource Template_Play}"
                                     IsChecked="{Binding PlayState, Converter={StaticResource PlayStateToCheckedConvert}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:ePlaybackState.ePlay}}" >
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked" >
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PlayCommand,
                                                                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:VMSPlayBarControl}}}" >

                                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </RadioButton>

 <Style TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="StyleRadioButton" >
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="Template_Play" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse x:Name="Part_BgEllipse" Style="{StaticResource StyleEllipse}" />
        <Image x:Name="PART_Image" Source="{StaticResource ImgPlayOff}"  Style="{StaticResource StyleImage}"/>
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Part_BgEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBlueColorBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource ImgPlayHover}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Part_BgEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource SecondaryLightGrayColorBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Any suggestions or ideas on the issue above ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's caused due to a binding issue. 
You're binding you radio button's IsChecked property to ViewModel property as some incorrect data type in your **ConvertBack** function in your converter. Please post your converter code also.

Anyways try this and check if it works.

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return Binding.DoNothing;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems to have fixed the issue. It seems ii was returning the value parameter instead of returning Binding.DoNothing as mentioned by yourself. thanks.